# How to use =COUNTIF() on every second cell that contains a letter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1. I want to keep track of employees working hours for the month which will include leave hours and overtime.
2. I'm using two cells for each day of the month. Cell 1 = how many hours worked/employee was on leave. Cell 2 = how many hours overtime
3. The working hours cell for the day will either contain a number(for how many hours they worked that day) or a letter(a "V", which will indicate they were on leave for the day).
4. Each "V" will count as 8 hours of leave.
5. I need to count every second cell in the range, starting at the 1st cell moving to the 3rd cell and so on. The 1st cell will be used for hours worked/leave and the 2nd cell will be used for overtime hours. So I need a formula to skip over the overtime cells.
6. I want to use a =COUNTIF() formula on the range to count how many times the letter appeared. The letter will then add 8 hours to the total leave cell.

At the moment I'm just selecting each cell and adding an IF formula to it. But I have to do it 35 times. I pasted the formula I currently had to type to achieve the results I need. But I have to repeat the formula for other cells in my sheet(which will use other letters) and if I want to change the letter "V" to anything else I'll have to go and change each "V".

```
=IF(B5="V",8)+IF(D5="V",8)+IF(F5="V",8)+IF(H5="V",8)+IF(J5="V",8)+IF(L5="V",8)+IF(N5="V",8)+IF(P5="V",8)+IF(R5="V",8)+IF(T5="V",8)+IF(V5="V",8)+IF(X5="V",8)+IF(Z5="V",8)+IF(AB5="V",8)+IF(AD5="V",8)+IF(AF5="V",8)+IF(AH5="V",8)+IF(AJ5="V",8)+IF(AL5="V",8)+IF(AN5="V",8)+IF(AP5="V",8)+IF(AR5="V",8)+IF(AT5="V",8)+IF(AV5="V",8)+IF(AX5="V",8)+IF(AZ5="V",8)+IF(BB5="V",8)+IF(BD5="V",8)+IF(BF5="V",8)+IF(BH5="V",8)+IF(BJ5="V",8)+IF(BL5="V",8)+IF(BN5="V",8)+IF(BP5="V",8)+IF(BR5="V",8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but here's an example of a range B5:N5 with four Vs. The formula is checking every second column (`MOD(COLUMN(B5:N5),2)=0`) and returns `8` if the value equals `V`. Note that this is an array formula so it needs to be entered using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

As there are four Vs, the result is 4*8=32. You can easily adjust/extend the range `B5:N5` as required.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(MOD(COLUMN(B5:N5),2)=0,IF(B5:N5="V",8),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT and Check if the COLUMN is even:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISEVEN(COLUMN(B5:N5))*(B5:N5="V"))*8
```

This is entered normally.

Answer (score 1):

It look like your range B5:BR5 will contain either a number or a letter "V"

Then,

for count the total number of "V" then multiply by 8,

the formula is :

```
=COUNTIF(B5:BR5,"V")*8
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest. No array formulas, no SUMPRODUCT, and uses the function specified by the OP. +1.

Comment: @Gravitate but it also assumes that the other columns do not have the letter in them.  Which may or may not be the situation.  If C5 has `V` it will get counted.  Again may not matter, which if is the case, I agree this is the better, but it does make an assumption not present in the OP's question.

Comment: @scottcraner it does. But even so, the premise is good. Even if other unwanted columns contained a "V", the formula could easily be adapted to look at a helper row which could identify the desired columns.

Comment: @Gravitate but again you make an assumption that a helper row is possible.  I am just stating that given what we know by the OP about wanting to do every other other column `I need to count every second cell in the range` this does not satisfy that.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I do make that assumption. But it is very rare that a helper row would not be possible. If absolutely required, it could even be placed on another sheet altogether. However, I really don't think a helper row is required. It is clear that a "V" indicates 8 hours of leave and every other column is used for overtime. A "V" in the overtime column would not make sense. If it did, it may want to be included anyway. I agree it doesn't technically do *exactly* what the OP asked. But depending on interpretation, I think it is the simplest answer which would do what the OP intends.